# Geometrically seeing the linking of the fibres in the Hopf fibration?

Tags: general-topology, fibration, hopf-fibration

I'm working through the following document: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.1205.pdf

I can understand the construction of the Hopf map using the Riemann sphere but I struggle to understand the geometric argument in section 4.3, 'the fiber circles are linked'.

The author mentions an equitorial sphere in $S^3$, $E$,  which is of course obtained by setting $x_4 = 0$. Now we consider the fiber $F$ that lies along the equator of the equitorial sphere where $x^4 = 0$.

Now we want to show that any other fibre of the Hopf map can connect any other point in $S^3$ to antipodal points along $E$. If the point on $S^3$ is $(z_1, z_2$) I can use a complex number $\lambda$ in order to 'rotate' the fiber into the plane of  $x^4 = 0$.

I really then struggle to understand how this shows that the fibers are linked by following this geometric argument. I would appreciate it if someone could clarify the steps/logic/etc.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the stereographic projection of this situation. Imagine a $2$-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with a blue equator, and there is another orange circle intersecting opposite hemispheres (at red points). I think it should be relatively evident these two are linked!

[image]

For more details, you should be able to slide the red circle to be as far away from the blue one as possible: namely, the line that the blue circle is wrapped symmetrically around (this corresponds to a circle in $S^3$ through the pole we project from - in this case the two circles are in orthogonal planes). Throughout the whole sliding process (using the action of $S^3$ on itself), the red circle never intersects the blue circle, so whether or not they're linked doesn't change. Then the complement of the blue circle retracts onto the red circle (within $S^3$, or $\mathbb{R}^3$ with a point at infinity). Thus, the red circle repreents a nontrivial element of the complements' fundamental group, which isn't possible if it isn't linked.